# Google maps dynamic load not showing

Tags: javascript, google-maps

We are trying to dynamically load Google maps for business (not using key but using client ID) using callbacks and HTTPS. Using the code below we are unable to get the maps to show.
Is there a correct JavaScript/URL to use with HTTPS, client ID and callback that works.

Hope someone can help.

```
function StartMap() {
    var script = document.createElement("script");
    script.src = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false&client=gme-CLIENTIDHERE&callback=LoadApis";
    script.type = "text/javascript";
    document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(script);
}

function LoadApis() {
    google.load("maps", "2", { "callback": LoadMap });
}

function LoadMap() {
    //Code here
}
```

Comment: Just out of curiosity, have you tried contacting Google Maps API for Business support? There are people ready to answer your questions, and if you have MA4B, then you are entitled to that support.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you're doing it wrong.

`StartMap` needs to load [google loader](https://developers.google.com/loader), not google maps, then the loader can load the maps for you, and you can add extra query params via the `other_params` option:

```
function StartMap() {
    var script = document.createElement("script");
    script.src = "https://www.google.com/jsapi?callback=loadMaps";
    script.type = "text/javascript";
    document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(script);
}

function LoadApis() {
    google.load("maps", "2", {"callback": LoadMap, "other_params": "sensor=false&client=gme-CLIENTIDHERE"});
}
```